# Can systemd be used to dynamically set a system-wide write bandwidth limit for a block device?

Tags: systemd, block-device, cgroups

I would like to dynamically set a system-wide limit on the write bandwidth for certain block devices.

The devices are pluggable and managed by our own service. Currently the service sets/removes the limit by writing to `/sys/fs/cgroup/system.slice/io.max` and `/sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/io.max` (`machines.slice` normally doesn't exist on our machines, but it would be nice to cover that, too). But I understand that these files are managed by systemd and our service shouldn't write them directly, and rather use some API to tell systemd to do it.

However, I found no way to do that with systemd, it seems to be a very uncommon use case.

The background for setting the limit is that certain models of the device don't implement proper thermal management, and the limit is needed to protect them from overheating. Other models don't need this limit and should use their full performance.